# Explode variable from space and append basedir in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

In my use case I am reading directories from conf and source path is space separated. Number of space separated source may increase or decrease. My `product.conf` look like below

**product.conf**

```
{
    "directories": [{
        "source": "src/main/php/en/path1 src/main/php/en/path2 src/main/php/en/path3",
        "lang": "en"
    }, {
        "source": "src/main/php/jp/path1 src/main/php/jp/path2",
        "lang": "jp"
    }]
}
```

Playbook to read conf and assign source into separate variable.

**playbook.yml**

```
---

 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local

   vars:
     BASE_DIR: /home/roop

   tasks:
     - include_vars: product.conf

     - set_fact:
         en_source="{{ item.source }}"
       with_items: directories 
       when: item.lang == "en"

     - set_fact:
         jp_source="{{ item.source }}"
       with_items: directories 
       when: item.lang == "jp"

     - debug: var=en_source
     - debug: var=jp_source
```

I am getting **BASE_DIR** dynamically. I need to add this **BASE_DIR** with every source. like

```
"en_source" = "/home/roop/src/main/php/en/path1 /home/roop/src/main/php/en/path2"
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hacky:

```
- set_fact:
    en_source="{{ BASE_DIR + '/' + item.source | regex_replace('(\s)', '\\1' + BASE_DIR + '/') }}"
```

`regex_replace` is a [filter from Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters).

For a cleaner solution you can create a [custom filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins).

Comment: Thanks for response. I am getting error `ERROR: There was an error while parsing the task .. Make sure quotes are matched or escaped properly`

Comment: You might have changed something. It's definitely working, copied from a working playbook. If you really get this error without changing any character, what Ansible version are you running? That was tested with 2.0.0.2

Comment: Oh my bad. its working. I missed last comma. I marked as a solution . Thanks a lot..